# Change section heading conditional on if text follows

Tags: sectioning, conditionals

I am writing a book with computer projects, My subheadings are numbered and in the format 'Task 1', 'Task 2' etc.
The current code in the def file is:

```
\titleformat{\subsection}  
 [hang]% shape  
  {\normalfont\large\itshape}% format applied to label+text  
  {Task \thesubsection}% label  
  {1em}% horizontal separation between label and title body  
  {}% before the title body    
  []% after the title body
```

However, I want two versions of this: If I don't specify a text after the title body, I just want it to remain 'Task 1', 'Task 2', but if I *do* specify some text, say 'Random Numbers', I want it to add a colon and the text, to read 'Task 1: Random Numbers'.

How would I do that? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last mandatory argument to `\titleformat` can end with a one parameter macro, which will be fed the title. We can check whether the title is empty.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\subsection}  
  [hang]% shape  
  {\normalfont\large\itshape}% format applied to label+text  
  {Task \thesubsection}% label  
  {0pt}% horizontal separation between label and title body  
  {\perhapscolon}% before the title body    
%  []% after the title body  

\newcommand{\perhapscolon}[1]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    % empty argument, do nothing
  \else
    : #1%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\subsection{Test}

\subsection{}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @PeterHoffmann If you like egreg's answer and it was helpful, please marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).